# how to display twitter feeds in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, twitter

how to display twitter feeds of a specific user account in iphone sdk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can fetch tweets of specific user from below link:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=**username**&count=25&page=1

and use any parser like NSXMLParser to parse the above feed. Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Do you have a specific code containing NSXMLParser which I can try. That would be great.

Comment: Please give me your email Id and I'll mail you the code but you have to try accommodate with your code as per your requirements.

Comment: sure..I will. Please use succeedebay@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks. I received the email. I will check it in a while and let u know. Thanks :)

Comment: The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.

Answer (score 1):

This is very generic question. However for starters you can do the following

1. [Authenticate](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/) your app using Oauth
2. Check out the APIs to fetch feeds from the [twitter api site](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage).
3. You can create custom widgets to display or use [uitableview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to add the data.

Comment: I think, We only need oAuth if we want to update user's status on his account.