# How to fetch twitter feeds in to iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, twitter

I want to fetch the twitter feeds from twitter in my iphone app.

How can I do it?

Comment: What did you try? What examples did you look at?

Comment: try to do some and ask where you got problem. Don't expect whole solution here

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455057/how-to-display-twitter-feeds-in-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0):

URLPath is a string with format :
 https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=40&user_id=your_user_id&screen_name=screen_name_you_want

```
    TWRequest *twRequest = nil;
    NSURLRequest *postRequest = nil;

    twRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLPath]
                                    parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *twitterAccountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    ACAccount *twitterAccount = [[accountStore accountsWithAccountType:twitterAccountType] objectAtIndex:0];

    if (twitterAccount) {
        twRequest.account = [accountStore accountWithIdentifier:((ACAccount *)twitterAccount).identifier];
        postRequest = [twRequest signedURLRequest];

        connectionRequest = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
        if(connectionRequest)
            responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
     }
```